# Azure AD B2C Redirect URIs to a different website on same domain

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to redirect the user to a different website on the same domain after authenticating the user? If it is, does it also work with multiple sites all hosted at *.azurewebsites.net?

So for example I have three sites:

`https://site1.mydomain.com`, `https://site2.mydomain.com` and `https://details.mydomain.com`.

All three are setup to connect to the same B2C, each have a separate user flow for authenticating the user. However when a user logins to either of Site1 or Site2, instead of directing the user back to the site that they started at, I instead want to send them to an authenticated page at the Details site, eg: `https://details.mydomain.com/account/main?source=site1`, where they can carry out some actions. Once complete, they can click a link on the details site to pass them on to a url at the original site where they are already authenticated.

I've tried updating the Redirect URIs value of site1 & site2 to the details site, which forwards the user to that site when they are authenticated. However, when I then try to open an authenticated url at Site1, this tries to authenticate the user again (which I don;t want it to do, as surely the user is already authenticated?) and I end up back at the details site.

Answer (score 0):

In the .Net Solution under the Account Controller you can control where the redirect happens. Below is the example:

```
public void SignUpSignIn(string redirectUrl)
    {
        redirectUrl = redirectUrl ?? "/";

        // Use the default policy to process the sign up / sign in flow
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl });
        return;
    }
```

Refer the link to get the solution : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

Also make sure that below configuration is done for SSO in the User Flow:

[image]

Comment: This is what I already have and redirects the user back to the site that they signed in from. Then when I change the source of this value to the other site, then I get the issue above with not being able to get to any authenticated urls on the original site.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you share the code which will help in doing the troubleshoot. 
Generally speaking when you are using the same B2C and your session is configured for Tenant, once you authenticated it will not ask to authenticate again. Your B2C session created in ***.b2clogin.com** .

Comment: When I have two sites that share the same B2C, then the second one automatically authenticates that user without having to re-enter any details.The problem is when I point the redirectUri of site1 to site2. At that point, after authenticating and being directed to site2, if I try to open a page on site1, I get sent round the authentication process again and end up back on site2. Making it now impossible to get to site1.

Comment: If possible May I know the types of apps you created, eg: C# MVC . Also, if possible can you check in the network tracer whether any error is there by preserving log.

Comment: The problem is that you started an OWIN session in App 1, and then send the result to App 2. So App 1 never sets an auth cookie. App 1 then needs to attempt to auth the user again. The way to "fix" this, is to always sent the user back to the App they came from. But use a state parameter that sends the user to App 2 after they arrive back to App 1 via AAD B2C. This way App 1's OWIN cookie is dropped properly.

Comment: @JasSuri If we authenticated once to B2C, B2C session gets created and whenever the app redirect to B2C login page it should automatically logged in. Please correct me if this is not the case.

Comment: That’s correct, but the app itself will not be “logged in” unless the app gets a token and sets its own cookie. That’s why you see the round trip in App 1 again, but the use should not be promoted for credentials, it should be SSO.

Comment: Exactly, user shouldn't be asked again to give the credential as B2C session already exist. The flow will run in a loop as App1 doesn't get the token as you mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @JasSuri, that makes sense, thanks! I'd come across the state parameter, but wasn't sure if I should use it or not, so it's good to have some confirmation that that is the best approach to redirect after returning to the original application.